# Which version of jQuery does noUiSlider require?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm using (trying to use) [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/). But I'm experiencing a strange problem and I think it's because I'm using an earlier version of jQuery.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 . Does anyone know which version noUiSlider requires?

Comment: what is the problem are you facing?

Comment: @coder The slider works if I click the "track", but not the handle. It gives this error in the console :TypeError: q.replace is not a function . And it points to line 102 of jquery.1.4.4.min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's **`noConflict()`** function to include two different versions of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="older_version_of_jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Do slider work
    //...

    $.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="newer_version_of_jquery"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I'm using Drupal, so I can't just change the version of jQuery, but including it twice worked, and I didn't even have to use noConflict(). Thanks